# SoundPool stop function not stopping

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm making an app, where you can choose from 1 to 4 different sounds and play them in the same time. Everything works fine till I want to stop sounds, function stop works only for one sound at the same time, here is the code (only for soundpool)

```
sound = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        s1 = sound.load(Main.this, R.raw.mosq1, 1);
        s2 = sound.load(Main.this, R.raw.mosq2, 1);
        s3 = sound.load(Main.this, R.raw.mosq3, 1);
        s4 = sound.load(Main.this, R.raw.mosq4, 1);
.
.
.
.
        case R.id.play:
            if (l1==true){sound.play(s1, 1, 1, 0, rep, 1); if(vib==true) wibracja.vibrate(4500);}
            if (l2==true){sound.play(s2, 1, 1, 0, rep, 1); if(vib==true) wibracja.vibrate(6500);}
            if (l3==true){sound.play(s3, 1, 1, 0, rep, 1); if(vib==true) wibracja.vibrate(2500);}
            if (l4==true){sound.play(s4, 1, 1, 0, rep, 1); if(vib==true) wibracja.vibrate(4500);}
            break;
        case R.id.stop:
            sound.stop(s1);
            sound.stop(s2);
            sound.stop(s3);
            sound.stop(s4);
            wibracja.cancel();
            break;
```

How to use stop function properly ? Thanks for help

Answer (score 11):

This is a common issue for those using SoundPool for
the first time. If you look carefully at the docs for SoundPool, play uses the parameter "soundID", while stop uses the parameter "streamID". It's easy to overlook this and use the soundID returned from the load function for both commands, as your code does. I've even seen android tutorial examples get this wrong. Instead use these commands:

```
s1 = sound.load(Main.this, R.raw.mosq1, 1);  
if (l1==true){p1=sound.play(s1, 1, 1, 0, rep, 1);     
sound.stop(p1);// NOT s1
```